# How to interpret Matiyasevich–Robinson–Davis–Putnam in term of algebraic geometry or geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, computability

As we know some algebraic problem may be presented or interpret into algebraic geometry or geometry, so we can understand the problem throughly.

Now, how to interpret  Matiyasevich–Robinson–Davis–Putnam in term of algebraic geometry or geometry? What does the "there is no algorithm to decide $\cdots$" mean in term of geometry?

Comment: Hope there is a beautiful and suprising interpretation.

Comment: Do you mean the impossibility to decide whether a diophantine equation is solveable, and if yes, whether it has finite or infinite many solutions ?

Comment: @Peter yes, and relevant. Some mad/ suprising idea, such as computational complexity is a distance, unsovability is as far as infinity distant

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115430/what-is-the-geometry-of-an-undecidable-diophantine-equation

Comment: @MoisheCohen good, thank you for the reference, it seems that undecidable has not interpreted into infinite distance.